# Circular JPanel Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, geometry

I am trying to display a circular object in my gui, the circular object should contain a few labels therefore I thought the circle object should extend JPanel. Does anyone know how to make a circular JPanel? Or at least a JPanel which paints an oval and places a few JLables in the centre of the oval?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a Circular Panel? Do you want to render a circle on it, or should your components be arranged in a circle?

Comment: Hi, I've just updated the question. I want to render a circle and have 2 JLabels stacked on top of each other in the centre of it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To paint a circle, subclass `JPanel` and override `paintComponent`:

```
public class CirclePanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(0, 0, g.getClipBounds().width, g.getClipBounds().height);
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[alt text http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/3708/so2343233.png](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/3708/so2343233.png)

To place the labels, you could use [`GridBagLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), hope that's what you want:

```
CirclePanel panel = new CirclePanel();

panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints gc;

gc = new GridBagConstraints();
gc.gridy = 0;
panel.add(new JLabel("Label 1"), gc);

gc = new GridBagConstraints();
gc.gridy = 1;
panel.add(new JLabel("Label 2"), gc);
```

[alt text http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/4013/so23432332.png](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/4013/so23432332.png)

Comment: can you add labels to the centre of the oval?

Answer (score 0):

In the book Swing Hacks from O'Reilly there is a hack for transparent and animated windows #41. The source code can be downloaded from http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596009076/